# How to do a user image upload - Django

Tags: python, django

I really need a lot of help with this and I dont know where to start since **I am new to Django** so excuse my ignorance.

I'll explain. I am building kind of a **image uploading-based page**. The images are grouped into albums. I created the album model and the image model which belongs to an album and it has its foreign key. But I dont know **how to do the upload itself**. I **thought** I **just** had to **handle the data** taken from the template in the views.py file **and** kind of **upload it**; but I am getting confused with some things I saw about a form... I dont know. I have no idea.

*So its simple: How do I upload the image and register a new row in the database, submitting all the additional data (like pic description) the module requires? Please help with this.*

Comment: Define a model with Imagefield and upload_to directory and create model form for the same.

Comment: @Dheerendra sorry but as i said i am new and I dont know anything about forms and how to use, I have already listened that but as i said I dont know where to start. I would really appreciate a few minutes of your time, please

Comment: you should read [this](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/forms.html) chapter from the tangowithdjango book. I hope this will clear your doubts and give you some direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are confuse about `django forms`. If you define the `forms.py` and simply do `{{ form }}` will render all the field in html so you don't need to worry about defining in html form field. or Don't use form... Define all the field by yourself `(!mportant Client side validation is must )`

Write the views like save the file into Image Table that's it. If you need anyhelp here . Happy to assist you ..

Comment: thanks, but what's the thing about important client side validation is must? and what code to write to save the image? Thanks though

Comment: @wonderwhy I did mention client side validation bcse if no `form.py` then the submitted form will hit the server and return error. So that we need  `javascript validation`. And you want to save image code ?

Comment: ah ok. Nah, its ok. I have to try it myself. Thanks. If I have any question I'll ask you.